# Validate a user input string to match specific pattern using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate a user input string to match specific pattern using regex in java. user input needs to match the following syntax: sv32i-a- where "sv" is always mandatory followed by 32 or 64, then "i" or "c"  then "-" then "a" or "b" then "-" and then  " " an empty space and then a possible repetition on the string like (sv32i-a- sv64c-b- ). Just getting confused. Thank you!

```java
public class StringValidation {
    static boolean result = true;

    //Help needed here. 
    static String syntax = "^rv\\d{2}$"; //Code goes here but not sure about the syntax..

    public static boolean isTrue(String stringToValidate) {
        result = stringToValidate.matches(syntax);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sv           here "sv" is always mandatory
(?:32|64)    followed by 32 or 64,
[ic]         then "i" or "c"
-            then "-"
[ab]         then "a" or "b"
-            then "-"
             and then " " an empty space
(?:xxx)+     and then a possible repetition on the string like (sv32i-a- sv64c-b- )
```

So: `(?:sv(?:32|64)[ic]-[ab]- )+`